# The $C^k$ Sheaves

Tags: differential-geometry, sheaf-theory

In *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*, the authors claim that $C^k$ are all sheaves because differentiability is local. How do I *formally* prove this?

Comment: Are using the vocabulary of Grothendieck topologies or are you working with sheaves on the opposite category of the topology of a space?

Comment: @k.stm I'm working on the latter, $\mathcal O(X)^{\text{op}}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, $C^k$ are functors ${\mathcal O(X)}^\mathrm{op} → \mathbf{Set}$.

Recall the definition of a sheaf: They are *sheaves* if for any open covering $U_α$ of some open subset $\bigcup_α U_α = U ⊂ X$ you have a glueing function on consistent systems $(s_α)$ of sections on $(U_α)$, i.e.:

- For all systems of sections $(s_α)$ in $C^k(U_α)$
- which are consistent on intersections, i.e. $∀α,β:~s_α|_{U_α∩U_β} = s_β|_{U_α∩U_β}$
- there is a unique glued-together section $s ∈ C^k(U)$
- which agrees with the given system, i.e. $∀α: s_α = s|_{U_α}$.

So, take an arbitrary open set $U ⊂ X$ and an arbitrary open covering $U = \bigcup_α U_α$, take an arbitrary system of functions $s_α \colon U_α → ℝ$ which are $C^k$ and agree on all intersections. Define a function $s\colon U → ℝ$ which is $C^k$ and agrees on all $U_α$ and prove such a function is unique.

To show that the defined function is $C^k$, you use that differentiability is a local property.

---

To say that the diagram
$$C^k(U) \overset{e}\rightarrow \prod_α C^k(U_α) \overset{p}{\underset{q}\rightrightarrows} \prod_{α,β} C^k(U_α ∩ U_β),$$
is an equalizer diagram in $\mathbf{Set}$, means exactly what I have written down before: Recall that

- $p((s_α)_α) = (s_α|_{U_α ∩ U_β})_{α,β}$
- $q((s_α)_α) = (s_β|_{U_α ∩ U_β})_{α,β}$, and
- $e(s) = (s_α)_α$.

The usual construction of the equalizer of the given diagram is the set
$$E(p,q) = \{(s_α)_α ∈ \prod_α C^k(U_α);~ p((s_α)_α) = q((s_α)_α))\},$$
which by the above interpretation of $p$ and $q$ is exactly the set of “consistent systems of sections” (for any presheaf $\mathcal F$, the elements in  $\mathcal F U$ are called “sections”), agreeing on the intersections.

To say that there’s a glueing function (as formulated above) is exactly to say that there’s a function $E(p,q) → C^k(U)$ commuting with $e$ (and the inclusion of $E(p,q) ⊂ \prod_α C^k(U_α)$), which is exactly to say that $C^k(U)$ is an equalizer as well: The glueing function gives a bijection, the inverse being given by the universal property of the equalizer.

Comment: @Exterior I added notes, hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: How does one formally show $e$ is an equalizer (in the sense of having the universal property)? I also don't understand what this "means exactly what I have written down before".

Comment: Intuitively it seems the pasting lemma more or less means $e$ is an equalizer, but again, I'm struggling with the formalism.

Comment: Let $ι \colon E(p,q) → \prod_α C^k(U_α)$ denote the inclusion. By the universal property of the equalizer, there’s a unique arrow $ψ \colon C^k(U) → E(p,q)$ making $e$ and $ι$ commute. On the other hand,there’s the glueing function $φ \colon E(p,q) → C^k(U)$ making $ι$ and $e$ commute. Therefore $ψ∘φ \colon E(p,q) → E(p,q)$ is an arrow making $ι$ and $ι$ commute. By the universal property of the equalizer (specifically the uniqueness of the universal arrow) this must be the same as $\mathrm{id}\colon E(p,q) → E(p,q)$. So $ψ∘φ = \mathrm{id}$ … (cont.)

Comment: (continuing) … On the other hand, $ι∘ψ = e$. But since $e$ is mono (pasting lemma, or rather: $\bigcup_α U_α = U$ – it’s a covering!), $ψ$ must be mono as well. Therefore, from $ψ∘φ∘ψ = ψ ∘ \mathrm{id}$ it follows that $φ∘ψ = \mathrm{id}$. (This argument “mono + right-invertible = iso” always holds.) Because both $ψ$ and $φ$ are commuting with $e$ and $i$, this gives an isomorphism of limits. As for the “written before”-part: Anything above the horizontal line, but also I explained this to more detail further below where I use the word “exactly” again (thrice).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19764/discussion-between-k-stm-and-exterior).